# Plot lines and vector in graphical gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, vector-graphics

Hello everyone does anyone have any idea how to do this type of graph.

I tried to plot the combination of lines and points but it still fails.

I think I have put a range to plot point to get the example I below.

dat.txt

```
0.936   1.735E-5
0.9317  1.682E-5
0.9274  1.633E-5
0.9232  1.588E-5
0.9189  1.545E-5
0.9146  1.504E-5
0.9103  1.466E-5
0.9061  1.431E-5
0.9018  1.396E-5
0.8975  1.364E-5
0.8932  1.333E-5
0.889   1.304E-5
0.8847  1.277E-5
```

For Plot

```
set xl 'Potential / V'
set yl 'Current / A'
plot 'dat.txt' u 1:2 w l lw 2 lt -1,\
'dat.txt' u 1:2 w p pt 2 ti ''
```

example of how it should be plotted

[image: Graphical]

Comment: Someone probably knows how to make it, but where have you encountered an error trying to make it?  If you are looking for an explanation of how to make it, that is far too broad for this site.

Comment: I can not do the graphics of this type in gnuplot just saw this picture and wanted to do a similar but just know plot lines. @Anonymous

Comment: You may want to read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My little knowledge is only with gnuplot wanted to illustrate this image and see if it was possible to accomplish the same. Sorry if it does not contribute to the community. @Anonymous

Comment: @FabioLima No problems, if you can improve the question with some work then I'm sure people here will be more than happy to help. You may very well be on to something useful and eventually turn this into a good resource. A few questions to think about would be: Where and why would you need this plot? What kind of data will be best represented by something like the plot above? Which Gnuplot plot style will be useful and what will generate the data? Can I come up with something that is similar to the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use vectors you can probably achieve what you want. A vector takes the following type of argument:

```
plot 'mydata.dat' a:b:c:d with vectors
```

The first two columns `a` and `b` are the starting point and last two `c` and `d` are relative coordinates of the vectors

Hence if you can compute these values from your data, you should be able to achieve the desired result.

```
set xl 'Potential / V'
set yl 'Current / A'
```

Define a custom arrow style that can be used:

```
set style arrow 1 head back filled linetype 1 linecolor rgb "red"  
set xrange [0.88:0.94]
```

Then define functions to compute the previous x, y values and the deltas

```
prev_x = NaN
prev_y = NaN
dx(x) = (x_delta = x-prev_x, prev_x = ($0 > 0 ? x : 1/0), x_delta)
dy(y) = (y_delta = y-prev_y, prev_y = ($0 > 0 ? y : 1/0), y_delta)
```

Finally plot them using the vectors command

```
plot 'stats.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 2 lt -1, '' u (prev_x):(prev_y):(dx($1)):(dy($2)) every 2 w vectors arrowstyle 1 ti ''
```

[image]

## Edit

After OP provided complete data [here](http://cl.ly/text/3T042y1J3p3W/download/date.txt), the script was changed to the following:

```
set xl 'Potential / V'
set yl 'Current / A'

set style arrow 1 head back filled size screen 0.015,20,35 linetype 1 linecolor rgb "red"  

prev_x = NaN
prev_y = NaN

dx(x) = (xd = x-prev_x, prev_x = ($0 > 0 ? x : 1/0), xd)
dy(y) = (yd = y-prev_y, prev_y = ($0 > 0 ? y : 1/0), yd)

plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 2 lt -1, '' u (prev_x):(prev_y):(dx($1)):(dy($2)) every 10 w vectors arrowstyle 1 ti ''
```

With the following graph:

[image]

Comment: If I have a dataset with negatives and positives axes, should I change the vector to monitor the entire curve. It is necessary to change the deltas?@Zahaib Akhtar

Comment: @FabioLima don't quite understand the positive and negative axis in the dataset, if you can post some model data.

Comment: Here link for date http://cl.ly/text/3T042y1J3p3W/download/date.txt for cycle complete model (negatives axis and positives). @zahaib-akhtar

Comment: @FabioLima Okay please see my updated answer with your provided data.